# How to return either Uni<Object> or Uni<Void>?

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, mutiny

```
@Route(...)
public Uni<?> call() {
    return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
}
```

throws a NullPointerException: Invalid value returned by Uni: `null`

However

```
@Route(...)
public Uni<Void> call() {
    return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
}
```

works perfectly fine and responds with HTTP 204

How do I manage to get either Uni<Void> or Uni<AnyObject> from the same method?
I need to return http 204 only in specific scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly as the types are different.
I would recommend using RESTEasy Reactive and do:

```java
@GET
public Uni<Response> call() {
   Uni<AnyObject> uni = .... ;
   return uni
      .onItem().transform(res -> {
        if (res == null) return Response.noContent().build();
        return Response.ok(res).build();
    });
}
```

By emitting a `Response` object, you can customize the response status.

Another solution if you want to keep using Reactive Routes is to not return a `Uni`, but get the `RoutingContext` as a parameter:

```java
@Route(...)
public void call(RoutingContext rc) {
   HttpServerResponse response = rc.response();
   Uni<AnyObject> uni = .... ;
   return uni
      .subscribe().with(res -> {
        if (res == null) response.setStatus(204).end();
        else response.setStatus(200).end(res);
    }, failure -> rc.fail(failure)); // will produce a 500.
}
```